# uikeyboard return

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have one view name:myplay.h and myplay.m

my view contain one textfield name txtplay..

It contain one button name btnplay.

In button event i want to check that if uikeyboard is open then close it.

I know below code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return TRUE;
}
```

and in button click event

```
-(IBAction)btnplayclick:(id)sender
{
  [self.txtplay resignFirstResponder];  
  ....
  ....
}
```

I want a global code to resign.

Comment: This one should do the job, what's wrong with that?

Comment: if i have 30 textfield i have to write for each..

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

From the doc:

> endEditing:
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
>
> - (BOOL)endEditing:(BOOL)force
>
> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i think to be generic and reuse your code anywhere is to create a category for the UIView :

```
@implementation UIView (FindFirstResponder)
- (UIView *)findFirstResonder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {        
        return self;     
    }

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [subView findFirstResonder];

        if (firstResponder != nil) {
            return firstResponder;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
@end
```

And then to call the method like that  :

```
-(IBAction)btnplayclick:(id)sender
{
  UIView *firstResponder = [self.view findFirstResonder];
  [firstResponder resignFirstResponder];

}
```

It does the tricks perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

or just write

```
  [self.view findAndResignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling resignFirstResponder on a UITextField that ISN'T first responder is a harmless no-op.

So go:

```
for (UIView *candidate in self.subview) {
    if ([candidate isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [(UITextView *)candidate resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```